# How to Define the selected option with the old input in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

Old Value in Select Option

`

```
<select class="form-select inp" name="die_categories_id" required>
                           <!-- <option value="">--------- select -------</option> -->
                            @foreach($DieManagementCategories as $DieManagementCategories)
                            <option value="{{ $DieManagementCategories->id }}">{{ $DieManagementCategories->die_number }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Change your `foreach` loop like this:

```
@foreach($DieManagementCategories as $DieManagementCategory)
```

And:

```
<option {{ old('die_categories_id') == $DieManagementCategory->id ? "selected" : "" }} value="{{ $DieManagementCategory->id }}">

{{ $DieManagementCategory->die_number }}

</option>
```

Comment: not warking this code bro

Comment: no bro not warking

Comment: What are you doing to test it?

Comment: edit and update my form

Comment: Add your update method to the post.